# How can I get Swell Foop (Same GNOME) working?

Tags: gnome, games

I've always loved this game but after upgrading to Ubuntu 10.10 the game was removed. Naturally I went into the Software Center and reinstalled it. However now when I launch it, it just freezes and will not do anything. I eventually have to kill it.

It shows this output in the terminal:

`(seed:12453): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion "G_IS_OBJECT (object)" failed`

Is there a known bug or something? How can I get this working again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug:

- [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-games/+bug/626016)
- [Upstream bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=624493)

Comment: It looks to have been fixed. http://goo.gl/d8FzC I just need to download the update (or I'll have to build from source).